# Remove Duplicates in Table Based on Multiple Column

Tags: excel, vba, duplicates, compare

Hello I want to compare 2 Columns in a Table and Remove the Duplicates if both Columns are the same.

For example:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/zKDqa.jpg

I did it with only 1 column but dont knwo how to compare 2 in code:

```
Sheets("A").ListObjects("Data").Range.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1), Header:=xlYes
```

Comment: `Columns:=Array(2,3)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To combine the two columns, you have to capture BOTH sets of the data as an array. This applies to removing duplicates on any data set range or table, as well as if you want to Filter on multiple members.

In your case since you want the second and third columns in your table evaluated, you can easily rewrite your code as:

`Sheets("A").ListObjects("Data").Range.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(2,3), Header:=xlYes`

Comment: Almost four years later... answer accepted... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If your data range called "data" then the code shall be:
`ActiveSheet.Range("data").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2), Header:=xlYes`